# Return a message when search item is not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How I could return a pop-up message that the search item is not existing? I have code below and it will just return a the heading portion on my table....

```
public ActionResult Index_PRFStatus(string searchBy, int id)
{
    List<purchaseOrder> po = new List<purchaseOrder>();
    po = db.purchaseOrders.ToList();

    if (searchBy == "close")
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        po = db.purchaseOrders.Where(x => x.prf_Id == id).Where(x => x.selected_supplier != null).ToList();
        return View(po);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(po.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("Item not found");` Is that what you mean by message box?

Comment: @puretppc This looks like it's in ASP.NET MVC though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript [alert()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) in the view if you really want a pop-up message. Or, you could just inform them on the page that there were no results:

```
@if (Model.Count == 0) {
    <span>No results found</span>
} else {
    // Make your table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your project in ASP.NET? If so, you cannot simply use MessageBox.Show. A better solution would maybe be to use javascript, like someone else implied.

Here's an example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "success", "alert('Could not be found'); {location.href='/Your.aspx';};", true);
```